# Datepicker for AngularJS with brackets on Controller.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, controller, brackets

I am new to angularJS on brackets and I am trying to do a datepicker from https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZvVxqg

When I paste the JS file into my controller.js in brackets, there is an error.

The following are the codes I have pasted in my controller.js which I dont know why it won't work

---

```
.controller('reservationCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', 
function ($scope, $stateParams) {



   $("html").click(function() {
  if ($("#icon_calendar").width() != 80) {
    ok = 0;
    $("#icon_calendar").css({
      width: 80,
      height: 80,
      borderRadius: "18px",
      marginLeft: -40,
      marginTop: -40,
      animation: "bounce2 0.3s",
      cursor: "pointer",
      transform: "scale(1)"
    });
    $(".mois").css({ display: "none", fontSize: 14, width: 80 });
    $(".days").css({
      fontFamily: "'openlight',sans-serif",
      display: "none",
      backgroundColor: "transparent",
      color: "#3C3C3C"
    });
    $("#month_wrap").css({
      backgroundColor: "transparent",
      color: "#F05252"
    });
    $("#month" + mois_choisi).css({ marginLeft: 0, display: "block" });
    $("#day" + jour_choisi).css({
      position: "absolute",
      fontSize: 30,
      width: "100%",
      display: "block"
    });
    $(".fleches_mois").hide();
    console.log("eee");
  }
});

$("body").on("click", "#icon_calendar", function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  if ($(this).width() == 80) {
    ok = 1;
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .   


setTimeout(function() {
  $("#day" + jour_choisi).css({
    position: "absolute",
    fontSize: 30,
    width: "100%",
    display: "block"
  });
}, 10);



}]);
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: It's not going to work well (if at all). Use directive for DOM manipulations.

Comment: An advice, if you are starting to learn javascript/angularjs etc, maybe before start to doing an application with an example you found with copy/paste, it's better if you understand all the things that you are programming. Take a look the angularjs tutorial in its official page, step by step!!

Answer (score 0):

Put that code into a directive and it should work:

```html
<div my-date-picker id="icon_calendar">
    <!-- date picker html -->
</div>
```

```js
angular.module('myApp').directive('myDatePicker', [
    function () {
        "use strict";
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function ($scope, $elem, $attrs) {
                // date picker code here
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

You'll still have to bind it to your model though.

Is there any reason you don't want to use any of the other date pickers with better drop-in support?:
[Angular-UI Bootstrap DatePicker](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#datepicker) (Angular 1)
[ng-bootstrap DatePicker](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/examples) (Angular 2+)

BTW, that code pen uses a very old version of angular 1.0.4 but it seems to work up to angular v1.4

Comment: oh, i didn't know that! i just used this datepicker because it looked quite nice. do you have any recommendations on websites for angularJS features?

Comment: @MavisSoon I sure do: [Admin Template with Date Pickers](https://colorlib.com/polygon/gentelella/form_advanced.html) which is one of [20 Free Bootstrap Admin Dashboard Templates](https://colorlib.com/wp/free-bootstrap-admin-dashboard-templates/)